# Black horizontal lines across BIOS on first boot

Tags: windows, graphics-card, bios

I've recently built a machine with the following components:

AMD Phenom II X4 840 3.2GHz processor
Asus M4A88TD-M EVO motherboard
PowerColor HD 6850 1GB graphics card
2 x G-Skill 4GB DDR3 1333MHz memory

Whenever I first boot the machine (each morning when I get into work), black horizontal lines are visible across the BIOS splash screen and also across the display when I see the hardware/memory checks etc. After the Windows loading screen (it's Win 7 Professional 64 bit), no video signal is output at all and I have to hard reset.

However... second time around, after the hard reset, it always boots fine with no problems whatsoever. As it only affects a cold booted PC, might it be somehow linked to the CPU temperature? If so, how would I resolve this?

Many thanks

Comment: Might be a monitor handshake issue.  You need to mention the brand & model of the monitor and type of connection (VGA or DVI or HDMI).  To test your temperature hypothesis, at the end of the day power off everything and then start up like in the morning.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention - the monitors are a Samsung SyncMaster BX2350 (which is the main display) and a secondary V7 L19WD. The connection is DVI to HDMI for the Samsung, DVI to VGA for the V7.

Comment: I had a similar issue that was caused by an external USB HDD. It may be worth unplugging things one by one to see if you can limit it to an external device.